# How does one use the SPEC drive to travel in an arbitrary direction in Vega Strike?

Tags: vega-strike

What if I want to just go really fast without a destination in mind?

Comment: Wow, it looks like my question is the first with a vega-strike tag. Thanks, fbueckert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I have found the answer to my own question. To toggle the SPEC drive on or off (with or without your targetting computer), you just press Shift-A, but the SPEC drive has no effect when you are either facing or close to gravity sources, meaning you can't use it to get closer to planets. When you're up close, you have to hold down the overdrive key for like 5 minutes. I thought I had the controls wrong, but I knew them all along. Essentially, you can't go really fast.